# Writing an SQLite manager class: viable approach?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm learning SQLite and C++ within the Qt framework. As a learning project I am doing a simple image viewer which enables the user to tag images with keywords, categories, comments and ROI (for some later OpenCV functionality). It's a pretty simple database with some primary tables and some relational tables.

I think I've got the basics down and early tests show that my record data is being stored but in writing the methods to manage the database it looks like I am going to end up with a great many methods, particularly when I start to add in searching, sorting, deleting, etc.

This leads me to ask if I am going about this the correct way.  I can see how some of my query logic (for search, sort) is probably better off being in a different "controller" type class and that all this manager class needs to do is handle the basic creation and deletion tasks, and just return a query object in response to a SELECT statement passed in as a string.

So, am I going about this in a reasonable way?

**Manager methods so far:**

```
bool openDatabase(QString name);
void closeDatabase();
bool createTables();
bool addKeyword(QString keyword);
bool addCategory(QString category);
bool deleteKeyword(QString keyword);
bool deleteCategory(QString category);
bool addROI(int x, int y, int width, int height);
bool deleteROI(int id);
bool addImage(QString name, QString path, QByteArray image, QByteArray thumb);
```

Comment: I'm also doing SQL with Qt. But I have just one function for inserting, deleting etc. Those function can be used for any table. Inserting for example takes the following arguments : table's name, columns and values.

Comment: @Davlog - yes, that makes sense. I can clearly get rid of a number of my methods that way. Have you found a way to to handle it when there are varying number of fields in a record? (ex: my `addROI` vs `addKeyword` above)

Comment: I posted my insert function, I hope this will answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen a `DatabaseManager` class somewhere and modified it. This is the insert function :

```
bool DatabaseManager::insert(const QString &tableName, const QString& columns, const QString &value)
{
    bool ret = false;
    if(db.isOpen()){
        QSqlQuery query;
        ret = query.exec( QString("INSERT INTO %1 (%2) VALUES(%3)").arg(tableName, columns, value) );
    }
    return ret;
}
```

You give it your table's name, the columns you want to fill and then the values. This is an example where I call it :

```
if( !dm.insert("Product", "ID, Name, Price, Notes, Category",
               "'1', 'A DVD','10€', 'Some Notes', 'DVD'") )
{
 //Note that each value is surrounded by an apostrophe
 //Now whatever you want to
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I finally got this approach working - those single quotes are tricky! I was trying to use the prepare/bindValue approach but this way is much more flexible. For reference, maybe this was the Qt/SQLite example you started with? :: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Inserting_a_row_into_a_database_in_Qt

Answer (score 1):

You probably should be using Qt's [Model View Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/model-view-programming.html). The important classes there are `QSqlQueryModel`, `QSqlTableModel` and `QSqlRelationalTableModel`. To keep your UI isolated from the database structure, a reasonable approach would be to add [view models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_model) for the particular use cases you have. You can then easily link those to, say, a Qt Quick based user interface.

There's nothing particularly wrong with function-oriented interface that you propose, except that it requires a lot of boring glue code to use it for user interfaces. It's best to factor such glue code as a proxy view model, since you're working to a documented API that can be then easily picked up by coworkers.